# discord.js Rich Embed in Command Handler

Tags: bots, embed, discord

I'm creating a few commands for my Discord Bot, but I cannot get rich embed to work. I'm using the following:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

    .setTitle("Bulbasaur")
    .setColor("#43A6DF")
    .setDescription("Seed Pokémon")
    .setThumbnail("image.png")
    .setURL("URL")
    .addField("Type", "Grass, Poison")
    .addField("Abilities", "Overgrow, Chlorophyll*")
    .addField("Pokédex", "Link")
message.channel.send("{embed}").catch(console.error);
}
```

If I simply use this, I'm having no issues:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
message.channel.send("pong!").catch(console.error);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? This is my message.js file in events folder:

```
  // Ignore all bots
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  // Ignore messages not starting with the prefix (in config.json)
  if (message.content.indexOf(client.config.prefix) !== 0) return;

  // Our standard argument/command name definition.
  const args = message.content.slice(client.config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // Grab the command data from the client.commands Enmap
  const cmd = client.commands.get(command);

  // If that command doesn't exist, silently exit and do nothing
  if (!cmd) return;

  // Run the command
  cmd.run(client, message, args);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question so I guess you solved it already but since I came here it means others can too...

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Bulbasaur")
    .setColor("#43A6DF")
    .setDescription("Seed Pokémon")
    .setThumbnail("image.png")
    .setURL("URL")
    .addField("Type", "Grass, Poison")
    .addField("Abilities", "Overgrow, Chlorophyll*")
    .addField("Pokédex", "Link");
  message.channel.send({embed}).catch(console.error);
}
```